# Style only the last showing Slick Slider slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I am using a Slick Slider that only shows 4 slides. The slides it rotates through are infinite.

I need the last slide showing to have different styling. I noticed the 4 current slides have the class `.slick-active` so with my styling tried `.slide.slick-active:last-of-type{}` however, this doesn't seem to work when the slider is set to infinite.

How can I get the current last showing slide to have different styling?

Comment: this might help you to get the last item https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828831/slick-js-on-last-slide-show-alert/31014377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this using JavaScript, you can add a new CSS class ('highlight') to the last slide using the following:

```
document.querySelector('.your-slick-slideshow').on('init'){
    // Get all of the slide elements
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.your-slick-slideshow .slick-slide');

    // If we have some slides
    if (slides.length) {
        // Add the 'highlight' class to the last slide in the list
        slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('highlight');
    }
});
```

Of course, you need to replace `.your-slick-slideshow` with the class corresponding to your slideshow.

Then you just need to add a style for `.highlight`:

```
.highlight {
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: Did this work out for you or do you have questions?

Answer (score 0):

you can change style with js I guess
you can do this

```js
$('.slides').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(nextSlide);
  if (nextSlide == 0) {
    // change style
  }

});
```

Comment: This is dependent on the direction the slideshow is moving. If you are moving backward through the slides (by using the 'previous' arrow or swiping) you will highlight the second slide.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to style the 4th slide, and only the 4th even after rotation by using the following CSS:

```
.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active
```

I just couldn't get the JS to detect if it was slide number 4. If I was to only want the second styled, it would be the following:

```
.slick-active + .slick-active
```